# Check box binds correctly but can't check or uncheck

Tags: html, checkbox, .net-core, popup, kendo-grid

In my custom Kendo grid popup editor, the check box binds correctly but can’t be checked or unchecked.

I could not find any posts relating to this issue.
I have tried the Keno check box (remarked out) and plain html.   I also tried to toggle the checkbox with an onclick JavaScript function, but that did not work either.  When you hover over the check box or label the cursor does change to a hand which indicates that it should allow me to click it.  The check box in my model is defined as public bool Active { get; set; }

I have the same issue when I use the default Kendo popup editor.  The Following code is for my custom editor and the grid view

```
@model Durendal.Core.ViewModels.Entities.Sku.SkuViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
        <div class="md-form md-bg">
            <input asp-for="BusinessLineName" class="form-control" />
            <label for="BusinessLineName" class="active">Business Line</label>
        </div>
        <div class="md-form md-bg">
            <input asp-for="Number" class="form-control" />
            <label for="Number" class="active">Number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="md-form md-bg">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <label for="Name" class="active">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="md-form md-bg">
            <input asp-for="Upc" class="form-control" />
            <label for="Upc" class="active">Upc</label>
        </div>

        @*<div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @(Html.Kendo().CheckBox().Name("Active"))
            </div>*@

        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="Active" id="Active" value="true">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="Active">Active?</label>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

```
@(Html.Kendo()
            .Grid<Durendal.Core.ViewModels.Entities.Sku.SkuViewModel>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(s => s.BusinessLineName).Width(60);
                columns.Bound(s => s.Number).Width(50);
                columns.Bound(s => s.Name).Width(140);
                columns.Bound(s => s.Upc).Width(70);
                columns.Bound(s => s.Active).Width(30)
                .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("# if (value == true) {# Active #} else {# Inactive #} # (Count: #= count#)");
                columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(90);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("_Sku"))
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(40)
                .Aggregates(aggregates =>
                {
                    aggregates.Add(s => s.Active).Count();
                })
                .Group(groups => groups.AddDescending(s => s.Active))
                .Sort(sort =>
                {
                    sort.Add("Number").Ascending();
                })
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Model(model => model.Id(s => s.Id))
                .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "Grid"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("SkuGrid_Read", "Customer", new { Id = Model }))
                .Update(update => update.Action("SkuGrid_Update", "Customer"))
                .Destroy(update => update.Action("SkuGrid_Destroy", "Customer"))
            )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this it's work for me..

```html
@(Html.Kendo()
            .Grid<Durendal.Core.ViewModels.Entities.Sku.SkuViewModel>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(s => s.BusinessLineName).Width(60);
                columns.Bound(s => s.Number).Width(50);
                columns.Bound(s => s.Name).Width(140);
                columns.Bound(s => s.Upc).Width(70);
                columns.Bound(s => s.Active).Width(30)
               .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #=value =='true'? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' value=''   />").Title("Active").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;" }).Width(100)
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("_Sku"))
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(40)
                .Aggregates(aggregates =>
                {
                    aggregates.Add(s => s.Active).Count();
                })
                .Group(groups => groups.AddDescending(s => s.Active))
                .Sort(sort =>
                {
                    sort.Add("Number").Ascending();
                })
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Model(model => model.Id(s => s.Id))
                .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "Grid"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("SkuGrid_Read", "Customer", new { Id = Model }))
                .Update(update => update.Action("SkuGrid_Update", "Customer"))
                .Destroy(update => update.Action("SkuGrid_Destroy", "Customer"))
            )
)
```

I create a client template for the check box..

And create a change function in javascript using the class..

```js
 $('#grid').on('click', '.chkbx', function () {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var grid = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid;
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
        if (checked) {
            $(this).attr("checked", true);
          //here you will get the click action....
           
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
           
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would work, but I finally figured out this morning that another partial view also had a check box for Active and it was conflicting with this one